# Specify CCSID while using FTP in AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am trying to transfer a file from one server to other server using FTP. Both the servers are in different ccsids. Is there any way to specify the CCSID while transferring through FTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that FTP will honor the ccsid of the files during the transfer, and do the conversion for you. Just make sure you are in EBCDIC mode rather than Binary mode, because binary mode does not do any conversions.

Note, if you are using FTP to create a new file on a remote IBM i machine, it will use the CCSID of the file being transferred. But if you create the file first, and give it a CCSID, and use EBCDIC mode, then FTP should do the conversion for you.

Edit: EBCDIC mode is similar to ASCII mode in that it is a text transfer process. This may only exist on implementations of the FTP protocol that exist on EBCDIC machines. Or maybe just on IBM i, VM, and MVS which all use EBCDIC. The help for EBCDIC mode says:

> The EBCDIC transfer type is useful when transferring files to or from another EBCDIC system because it avoids the need to translate between ASCII and EBCDIC on both systems.

It is a synonym for `TYPE E`.

Comment: Please elaborate on "ebdic mode". The FTP protocol knows about a binary mode and a text transfer mode (mode ascii). The latter allows for all kinds of conversions to keep the transferred content sensible.

Answer (score 1):

There is a FTP command `type` that lets you set the file transfer type.

The value 'C ccsid#' lets you assign a CCSID value.

`binary` appears to be a shortcut to `type i`.

`ascii` appears to be a shortcut to `type a`.